# mvc upload file with model - second parameter posted file is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a simple model with 1 string property which I render on a simple view.

the view looks like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { encType="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    <br /><br />

    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit me" name="submitme" id="submitme" />
}
```

Controller is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadFileModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   // DO Stuff
   return View(model);
}
```

Now, when I submit, the model DOES get populated but the second parameter being HttpPostedFileBase is null. However when doing Request.Files - it does seem to show there is a file in the Request being posted.
How can I actually get the second parameter to bind?

Comment: Binding happens by name, and since you have `name="fileUpload"` on the input markup, your action method's second parameter should be named the same i.e. `HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Why not add the uploaded files to your model like this:

```
public class UploadFileModel 
{
    public UploadFileModel()
    {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    }

    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // Rest of model details
}
```

Then change your view to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { encType="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    <br /><br />

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit me" name="submitme" id="submitme" />
}
```

Then your files will be posted back as follows:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadFileModel model)
{
    var file = model.Files[0];
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This worked. Thanks! But still makes no sense why it will not bind to the 2nd parameter. I would like an explanation for that though.

Comment: was just waiting for it to allow me to accept the answer - all done. I agree with you, the VM approach. It's just... mind boggling on why it wont bind the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Why do you use HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile?

Comment: reference m.Files.Files is incorrect.  Submitted edit

Comment: need to add HTML5 multiple attribute like so if you want to choose more than 1 file with same input control `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", name = "Files" })`

Comment: @hutchonoid what change I should make in my table in sql? It get error key not found? I think I should add a column to UploadFileModel table in database named Files, but don't know the type of column. Am I write?

Answer (score 15):

For dealing with a single file input you can define a `HttpPostedFileBase` property within the *ViewModel*:

```
public class SomeModel() 
{ 
    public SomeModel() 
    {
    }

    public HttpPostedFileBase SomeFile { get; set; }
}
```

And then implement it in the following way:

**View:**

@model SomeModel

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Submit", 
    "Home", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeFile, new { type = "file" })
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" 
        name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" />
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(SomeModel model)
{
    // do something with model.SomeFile

    return View();
}
```

In case you need to deal with multiple files, you can either:

- create multiple properties and implement them separately just like the one above;
- change the `public HttpPostedFileBase SomeFile` property to something like `public List<HttpPostedFileBase> SomeFiles` and then span multiple `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeFile, new { type = "file" })` controls to have them all within that list.

In case you need additional info check out [this blog post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-mvc-handle-one-uploaded-files-viewmodel-properties-using-httppostedfile-class/) that I wrote on the topic.

Answer (score 10):

Change your name `file` to `fileUpload` and `enctype` it's work

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    <br /><br />

    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit me" name="submitme" id="submitme" />
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadFileModel model, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{
   // DO Stuff
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I don't know why it's not working for you.It's perfectly working for me.

Comment: This approach was what I was looking for, direct approach, the missing part in my problematic solution was "enctype="multipart/form-data" }" in BeginForm :-/.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, (if acceptable) remove the [Required] validation annotation for your file from your model and check for the file in your Controller action, and add an error if not found:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionWithFileUpload(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var postedFile = Request.Files[0];
            if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string imagesPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"); // Or file save folder, etc.
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                string newFileName = $"NewFile{extension}";
                string saveToPath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, newFileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(saveToPath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "File not selected.");
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Or return view, etc.
}
```