# Why aren't file uploads binding to my viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, viewmodel, model-binding

I'm trying to bind file uploads to a ViewModel (as demonstrated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21677152/1778169)).

But I can't get the files to bind to the `Files` property on the ViewModel.

Please see the code below. What am I doing wrong?

*(Edit for clarity - I'd like the uploads to bind to the VM, not have them as an Action parameter.)*

**ViewModel**

```
public class PrimaryImageUploadViewModel
{
    public PrimaryImageUploadViewModel()
    {
    }

    public HttpPostedFileBase[] Files { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(PrimaryImageUploadViewModel postedModel)
{
    var requestFiles = postedModel.Files;  // THIS VALUE IS NULL - WHY?
    foreach (var f in requestFiles)
    {
        if (f.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            // do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="MyImage.png"
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEj8zSF9hwGU3ZQA9
Origin:http://localhost:52588
Referer:http://localhost:52588/example/edit/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryEj8zSF9hwGU3ZQA9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"

Some Test Title
------WebKitFormBoundaryEj8zSF9hwGU3ZQA9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="MyImage.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryEj8zSF9hwGU3ZQA9--
```

Comment: can you please post view?

Comment: The view is just a file input.  I use the blueimp file uploader to upload the images with ajax. It sends the Request Payload shown above.

Comment: Request Payload name is "files[]" but your model name is files.I thinks its due to the mismatch in name.

Comment: Shouldn't `files[]` in the request payload bind to the `postedModel.Files`?

Comment: I tried the same and the problem is with the name. I posted multiple file from  my page to the action method It worked

Comment: Thanks for your time spent. What change did you make to the name? The only difference I could see was to change the ViewModel `Files` to `files` (all lowercase).  But this doesn't make any difference when I do it.

Comment: both the array name in the model and the posted files input name should be same. Say if your model contain Files as HttpPostedFileBase[] than your file input name in the html or any other post data name should be the same Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
 public class Model1
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase[] Files { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes it does. It made me realise that I was looking at the wrong problem.  The name itself was `files[]` (with square brackets).  When I had thought it was an array of `files`.  Thank you very much. I appreciate your help and persistence.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure you've set the enctype `attribute` on your form to `multipart/form-data` on your form if you want to be able to upload files:

You can access uploaded file in post action parameter,

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(PrimaryImageUploadViewModel postedModel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
    {  
        string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
        string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFilesFolder"), _FileName);  
        file.SaveAs(_path);  
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Ideally I'd like the file uploads to form part of the `postedModel`, not have them as a separate parameter on the Action. Yes, it's posted as `multipart/form-data`.